# Angular mat menu position not working in full screen near trigger element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-9

I am using mat-menu to implement pop-up when clicked on button. I recently updated my project from angular 8 to 9 after which the position of pop-up gone out of page to left insted of it's specified position x-left y-right. And when I reduce size of chrome window it's works as expected. What could be possible reason for this and solution?

I tried adjustion x and y position as given in documentation. But it doesn't work. It was working in amgular 8 but in angular 9 it's not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!